# I cant update my VPCEC15FG to Windows 8

Tags: display-driver, ati-mobility-radeon, switchable-graphics

I am using a Sony VAIO VPCEC15FG computer.
I want to install Windows 8 in my system.

I successfully install it, but my graphics driver is nor t working well.

When I searched on the internet it says that ATI graphics card (ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 5650 Graphics) driver can't be installed on my laptop, because it has switchable graphics capability. Can anybody tell me how to get a driver for my device driver for Windows 8.

Comment: AMD doesn't provide graphics drivers for switchable graphics, go to Sony website and look there for drivers.

Comment: I already went there, but nothing found for windows 8

Comment: Windows 7 driver should work just as well.

Comment: No. I tried that. It says it is not compatible

Comment: Try older versions then, sometimes manufacturers upload invalid drivers.